# Angular 2 manually inject service into class?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to inject a service into a class that just has a constant.

The service I want to inject is this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationStart} from '@angular/router';
import {location} from '@angular/common';

enum Environment {
    local, 
    dev
}

@Injectable()
export class EnvService {
    private _env: Environment = Environment.dev;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location
    ) {
        this._env = someApiCallToGetEnv(); 
    }

    getEnv(): string {
        return Environment[this._env];
    }
}
```

And the class I want to inject it with is this...

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {ResourcesComponent} from 'components/resources.ts';

import {EnvService} from 'services/env.service';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: EnvService.getEnv() + '/resources',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'resources',
        component: ResourcesComponent,
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Depending on the environment, I want to have the redirect link be dynamic when a user navigates to the root of the website when they first navigate to it.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can create a pattern only for routes

Comment: Btw what should getenv method return ?

Comment: it returns one of the environment enums as a string. There's more I didn't list.

Comment: The environment variables should be use statically in frontend in your case or secong thing create a route link `:myroute/resources` now whereever you redirect with any env url after run the app it'll work

Comment: @BabarBilal that's at the root ' '. Where can I add for instance :env at the root/application level?  If I add   ` {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: ':env/resources',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },`

Comment: @BabarBilal I ended up using an event listener on the router at the app.component.level - and navigating to the correct url  with the env service injected in there. Thanks for your help

Comment: Resolving the environment dynamically is not a good way to handle things. Likely an XY problem.